# slideDelay is not working in particlesliderjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm facing an issue right now and I guess I need your help to solve it out, I've created a particle slider in particlesliderjs and in  that I have tried to stop automatic slide change by slideDelay as mentioned [here](http://particleslider.com/documentation/api#ParticleSlider.slideDelay) but in my case it's not working and it is assuming is default value 0. 
Please help me out thank you.. :)

```
<body id="logos">
<div class="controls">
<div class="left" data-src="images/left.png"></div>
<div class="right" data-src="images/right.png"></div>
</div>
<div class="slides">
<div id="first-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/290px-Sony_Alpha_logo.svg.png">
</div>
<div id="second-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/lgCrssn.png">
</div>
<div id="third-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/Patrick-Jane-patrick-jane-23242604-500-281.jpg">
</div>
<div id="fourth-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/y-1b2a02600dd0fc5002a8c1ee5d642597.png">
</div>
</div>
 <canvas class="draw"></canvas>
<script>
var init = function () {
    var ps = new ParticleSlider({
        slideDelay: 0,
        mouseForce: 1000,
        monochrome: false,
        showArrowControls: true,
        ptlGap: 5,
        ptlSize: 2,
        arrowPadding: 15,
        sliderId: 'logos',
    });
    (window.addEventListener
            ? window.addEventListener('click', function () {
        ps.init(true)
    }, false)
            : window.onclick = function () {
        ps.init(true)
    });
    window.onresize = () => {
        ps.width = window.innerWidth;
        ps.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
}

var initParticleSlider = function () {

    var psScript = document.createElement('script');
    (psScript.addEventListener
            ? psScript.addEventListener('load', init, false)
            : psScript.onload = init);
    psScript.src = 'js/particleSlider.js';
    psScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(psScript);
}
(window.addEventListener
        ? window.addEventListener('load', initParticleSlider, false)
        : window.onload = initParticleSlider);

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to set the `slideDelay` after creating the *particle-slider* object.

```
var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    mouseForce: 1000,
    monochrome: false,
    showArrowControls: true,
    ptlGap: 5,
    ptlSize: 2,
    arrowPadding: 15,
    sliderId: 'logos',
});

ps.slideDelay = 0; //<-- set it here
```

<sub>***side-note:*** the default value for `slideDelay` is 10</sub>

Comment: that's perfect!